# What does "イタズラ書きだらけの壁にひとつの携帯番号." mean?

Tags: translation, manga, sentence

I am around N5 level (almost finished book that is a little bit over this level)  and so I decided to try learning some life language translating manga from raw and checking it in a translated version.  I use Noragami and it's my first day so the beginning. I found a sentence that is translated very differently than I did it with me not understanding why so if anyone could clarify what it literally says, I'd be grateful.

イタズラ書きだらけの壁にひとつの携帯番号。

If it helps: furigana for first kanji is ga,  then it's kabe,  at the end it's keetaibangou.

I kinda understand that it should end with something connected to a mobile phone number,  probably a lone one/only one and that there is an inscription on a wall. But I cannot understand those katakana and then hiragana parts and I cannot connect it into one sentence.
Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Sorry,  I have no clue what it says to me. I got lots of Japanese, probably some Japanese adds. As I said,  I'm not fluent at all.

Comment: Chrome suggested me translation so if I understand correctly it shows some sites connected to words in there,  right?  My problem is that I DO have a translated version from the fan translation.  And I have some dictionaries,  both online and book ones. But e.g. this itazura has over 10 options in different kanjis and the darake got something that does not fit into the translation.  And also there goes something with grammar that got me lost in the sentence. So basicaly I just wanted somebody to help me understand why it is translated this way and not just get the translation.

Comment: I did in not in English but I think it would be something like "Among useless/pranky writing shownig someone's mistakes on the wall there is/was a lone mobile phone number". In English version  it said "On the vandalised wall of the cubine there was a scrawled out phone number".

Comment: Where did you get "someone's mistakes" from?

Comment: So basicaly I don't see where it say something about the number being scrawled and that it was in a cubine.  And judging from these itazura meanings I got might be even something like a raped writings on a barier.

Comment: Probably a tangorin when I wrote the whole phrase.

Comment: Mhm,  it says.  Darake - implying (negatively)  that something is full of (mistakes)

Answer (score 3):

I think your interpretation of the sentence, ***a lone one/only one and that there is an inscription on a wall.***, is close.

I think 「イタズラ書きだらけ」is compound. It is strange to drop one word in the phrase.

So, do you want to parse the sentence a little bit for understanding the mix of ひらがな and カタカナ?

> ((イタズラ + 書き) + だらけ) + の + 壁 + に + ひとつ + の + 携帯番号。

[イタズラ書き](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%82%AA%E6%88%AF%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E3%83%BB%E5%BE%92%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D-203653) means *Doodles/graffiti/sketches,etc.*

[だらけ](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%82%89%E3%81%91-563186) means *(something like unnecessary stuff) scattered about, full of (often used negatively)* and the suffix to noun

「イタズラ書きだらけ」  Doodles/graffiti/sketches,etc. are spread out/scattered about.

> イタズラ書きだらけの壁にひとつの携帯番号。

*There's one/lone mobile phone number on the wall (about) which Doodles/graffiti/sketches,etc. are scattered (about)/spread out.*

Comment: So basicaly I tried to separate those in the beginning unnesseserly and had not that good translation of this darake.  And for some reason the other guy translating it had his own creativity shown and added something.  Thanks,  I think I get it.

Comment: And as far as I understand from other parts of manga,  it uses katakana for non-foreign words as a way to highlight something...  I think.

Comment: Probably it's using カタカナ just to emphasize lines, or the shape of drawings themselves rather than the concept of drawings.